# Django - Heroku - committing a change

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I've been asked to make some changes to a Django app on Heroku previously managed by someone who is no longer available.

I've not used Heroku before so I am hoping this is a really easy question.

I cloned the app using `heroku git:clone -a myapp`

I changed the `base.html` file.  I literally removed a few lines of HTML.

I then ran

```
git add .
git commit -m "Some helpful message"
git push heroku master
```

And I get this error traceback:

```
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 497 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Running pre-compile hook
remote: -----> Noticed django-wkhtmltopdf, bootstrapping wkhtmltopdf.
remote: -----> No runtime.txt provided; assuming python-2.7.3.
remote: -----> Using Python runtime (python-2.7.3)
remote: -----> Noticed pylibmc. Bootstrapping libmemcached.
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.2.1)
remote: ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
remote:     globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
remote:     raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
remote: ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
remote: ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
remote:     globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
remote:     raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
remote: ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
remote: ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
remote:     globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
remote:     raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
remote: ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
remote: ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
remote:     globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
remote:     raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
remote: ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
remote: ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
remote:     globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
remote:     raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
remote: ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
remote: ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 139, in <module>
remote:     globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
remote:     raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
remote: ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
remote:     load_entry_point('pip==1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 343, in load_entry_point
remote:     return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2307, in load_entry_point
remote:     return ep.load()
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2013, in load
remote:     entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
remote:     from pip.backwardcompat import walk_packages, console_to_str
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/backwardcompat.py", line 18, in <module>
remote:     import md5 as md5_module
remote:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/md5.py", line 10, in <module>
remote:     from hashlib import md5
remote: ImportError: cannot import name md5
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to app-portal.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/app-portal.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/app-portal.git'
```

The only file I changed was `base.html` so what's going on?

Comment: did u tried again with adding the same line in it?

Comment: try `git push heroku master --app_name`

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool - same traceback and error

Comment: try `git pull heroku master` then merge your code then push.

Comment: If you are sure of what you're doing you can force the push to heroku:

`git push --force heroku master`

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool - I'm not going to force it.  I'll try the pull

Comment: @UsmanMaqbool - I cannot workout how to pull directly from Heroku

Comment: @HenryM Try and check `requirements.txt` and see if all the libraries are up to date, then delete everything from `requirements.txt` and `pip freeze  >> requirements.txt` again, I think  something is not up to date

Comment: @PetarP - interesting.  The reqirements.txt is shockingly out of date.  They had to send me 6 zipped packages to setup on my laptop so I can test

Comment: @HenryM, Yea Heroku will check the `requirements.txt` before deploying the app, so I suppose you will solved it by fixing that, good luck

Comment: @PetarP - I fixed the requirements.txt and got the system up an running as a new app on Heroku - I've been using that to test and learn the system.  When I try to load the new requirements.txt file (which has been working) I get the same error as above.  Any thoughts?#

Comment: I assume that something is not installed properly, try implement TravisCI so you can see the whole deployment process, and you will found what is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out the issue.  The app is running on cedar-10 and Heroku have stated although the stack will continue to run, app updates are not supported or possible.